# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - After updating Android SDK & ADT

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

After updating SDK and ADT for the latest release, I tried to run my application and Eclipse log the following error:

```
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbr/com/digitalpages/renderer/NewReaderActivity;
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:282)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:363)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:545)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:524)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:123)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:702)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:923)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1126)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbr/com/digitalpages/commons/activity/LoadingActivity;
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:282)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:363)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:545)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:524)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:123)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:702)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:923)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1126)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[- RichReaderDemo] Dx 2 errors; aborting
[- RichReaderDemo] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this issue after updating to the October 2011 r15 version of ADT and SDK. My project uses 3 projects as libraries, so there is a lot of interdependence between the projects.  This error comes up (I believe) when the build tool sees the same object get defined multiple times.  My guess is Google changed up how the library references work, so my old project setup was no longer valid.

I tried messing with the project's library and build path settings, but I couldn't get the build to be stable.  The solution I came up with was to:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Make a backup copy of the workspace
3. Delete the .project and .classpath files in each project
4. Open a new workspace in Eclipse
5. Add the project back in using the *New Android Project* wizard (selecting "Create project from existing source"). Note: This is different from importing an existing project.

After I set up the library dependencies in the new workspace, everything compiled just fine.  I had a lot of settings I didn't want to lose, so I copied the regenerated .project and .classpath files back into my original workspace and it has been working alright for me so far.

Comment: Ah yes, your comment is much more succinct: "Create a new project"    :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should do Clean Project and rebuild it, solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

1) Delete the project (do no delete project contents from disk).
2) Delete the `.project` and `.classpath` files in the project.
3) Create new project with the current src (`Create project from existing source`)

Answer (score 2):

If this happens during export, delete files present in the bin directory of your project. and restart export. in less than 30 seconds is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project-> Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 5.0.1), You can keep android dependencies(if it doesn't contains any conflicting jar files). Do the same for order and export (in Project-> Properties->Java Build Path-> Order and export). Click OK. Clean the project. It should solve the problem.
It is caused due to jar conflicting issues.

Answer (score 0):

try [android update project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/android.html)

when you use some libs from workspace maybe you must remove link-rows to they in Project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Source

Answer (score 0):

I had a cmd window open in the bin/dexedlibs and when i cd to the parent (bin), that solved the problem for me.   So it appears to be very subtle build errors.  During a clean, the builder will remove the dexedlib folder, and perhaps that it gets an error during the rmdir will cause this failure also.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project is not necessary.

Just delete the gen and bin folder and press project clean.